# Crystal cave timing in "Blood of Amber"

Tags: chronicles-of-amber

When Merlin escapes with Luke to the crystal cave (leaving Vinta behind), he sees bones of those who were sent to for him:

> It would have been months since the pair who had removed the boulder
> had fallen there, long enough for scavengers to have done a thorough
> job.

In Amber time it was just a couple of days, so time flows is really very fast (about 1 to 30).
Merlin and Luke had some brief conversations, Merlin conjures the ladder, helps Luke down, creates a trump for the Arbor house and returns.

All this is not more then a couple of hours, may be even less then that.
In Amber time it would amount to just several minutes (120 min/30 = 4 min).
So Merlin should see Vinta writing a letter for him ("PUT THE BUTTON IN A SAFE PLACE...").
Actually Vinta could just get some coffee and wait for Merlin to return (she may know where he was going, or just sit and sort things out, decide on the next steps).

Instead of this Merlin returns in the evening:

> Beyond the window, the shadows of the trees were stretching into the
> east. I had obviously been gone for most of the day.

And real Vinta says she remembers things from the morning:

> "About what time did you become yourself again?"
>
> "This morning."

So several hours had passed or at least several days in crystal cave shadow time.

How could that be?